# SharePoint 2013 and SSL Offload / Termination

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, ssl, load-balancing

I'm trying to configure my SharePoint to allow SSL Offload.
I have a My Sites Host web app created on port 80 (without SSL) and I have configured Alternative Access Mapping to support the SSL Offload:

```
Internal URL --------------------------Zone ----------Public URL for Zone
https://my.companyname.com -----------Default --------https://my.companyname.com 
http://my.companyname.com ------------Default --------https://my.companyname.com
```

I'd like to obtain the following:

```
Client Network (Https) ----- Load Balancer ----- (Http) SharePoint Farm
```

The site can be viewed by the clients correctly, but my problem is that from within the SP farm network, when I navigate through the sites I sometimes get redirected to https and receive a "Page not found" (since the load balancer is here not involved).

How can I avoid the internal redirection without compromising the SSL Offload configuration?

Comment: did you try to access the site with Server name & port number? also try to create another URL and add that in the different zone(i,e intranet, internet)